# ssh to multiple servers in one go

Tags: powershell, ssh, devops

I have to login to multiple hosts at one time, sometimes the number is around 20. The user and pass are same for all the hosts.

Currently to ssh onto these servers I have to run the ssh command manually in power shell and enter the password.

Is there any way I can just provide the servers list along with user/pass and open multiple PowerShell windows in one go? (help me if that can be achieved using ps script)

Sometimes I have to run the same command on all hosts, for that I am using `mobaxterm`. But again, in this tool as well I have to ssh to servers one by one.

Is there any single tool which can do both the magics (ssh to multiple hosts in one go and I can run commands parallelly)

Comment: What do you intend to do after there's an SSH session?

Comment: Are you aware of loops in PowerShell?

Comment: This question I feel would be better placed at https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com. This is a usability question, not a programming one.

Comment: You can tackle this with PowerShell if you want to script it. I would suggest reading about [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.1), [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1), and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1) for an idea of looping in PS.